# Store Emails related to List Item

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-server, outlook

I have a requirement where user wants to store all the email correspondence of a list item from Outlook. I want to capture the date and subject of emails directly. I also want to mention that each list item has separate set of emails that they want to store.

So I'm guessing there is no option to setup a doc library and display all emails as a list view webpart inside list forms.

Can someone suggest any third party tools or approaches that I can follow to help me tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SharePoint 2013, then you can use the site mailbox functionality.

A site mailbox is a central email and document sharing account that is accessed from a SharePoint site. Your team may choose to use a site mailbox to gather relevant team-level email conversations or collaborate on composing an important email message. Your team may also find it helpful to share important documents securely by using a site mailbox.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/overview-use-a-site-mailbox-to-collaborate-with-your-team-HA103927690.aspx

http://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/sharepoint-site-mailbox-integration-with-outlook-a-new-way-to-get-email-into-sharepoint/

**there are other ways to do check this blog:**

http://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/five-out-of-the-box-ways-to-get-email-into-sharepoint/

Comment: Unfortunately we are still using SP 2010. Also, each list item has a separate set of email correspondence. So storing them in a central location wont help I guess.

Comment: did you check the last link, in that he is talking about manual ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks Waqas but none of the approaches can help my situation. Thanks again.